# How to populating Postgres database from a CSV with default values?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `charts` table in a `postgres` database:

```
charts (
  id: integer, 
  vendor_id: string, 
  rank: integer, 
  country: text, 
  genre: text, 
  created_at: datetime, 
  updated_at: datetime
)
```

I have to import data into the table from a csv file with following structure

```
id,country,genre,rank
```

I can import the file using

```
COPY charts(
              vendor_id,
              country,
              genre,
              rank
        )
        FROM [FILE_PATH] DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

However, I would like to populate `created_at` & `updated_at` columns with the creation timestamps. Is it possible to do it using the standard postgres `COPY` command.

If **NOT**, what would a better way to approach it?

======================================================

POSTGRES VERSION: 11.2

IMPORT FILE SIZE: > 5GB

Comment: You should use `COPY` to simply load it into a temporary table with all `text` type columns mirroring the main table. Then `Insert` it into the main table with required transformations(`to_timestamp` etc). That's generally the common practice.

Comment: Set a default value for those columns, e.g. `alter table charts modify created_at default current_timestamp;`